# SSIS Dynamic File Name Variable vs Parameter

Tags: ssis

I am New to SSIS. I have to fetch file name dynamically from a table. I have used parameters in my ssis package for storing the filenames in package. In the execute sql task i am planning to fetch the value from database and store it in parameters. What will be the best way to store filenames in package. Parameters or variables.

Comment: Variables.  Parameters are typically used to change values via the SQL server agent job.

Comment: @EricHauenstein So In my case Variables  what would be better!!Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You should use variables.

Variables are typically used to make tasks accept or use dynamic values.
Parameters are typically used to change values when scheduling packages in the SQL Server agent.

Either will work, but variables are the more common way to do it.